On the intuition of compactness in terms of the derived set
The usual definition of a compact set $K$ is that from every open covering of $K$, there exist a finite subcovering. This definition gives the idea that the notion of compactness is kind of a generalization of finitude. It is also worth noting that if $X$ is a finite set, $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ achieves maximum and minimum. For sets $X$ that are not finite, this result holds if $X$ is compact.
I have been given another definition of compact set in terms of the derived of a set:
"a set $K$ is compact if for all $A$ infinite set with $A\subset K$, it is true that $A'\cap K \ne \emptyset$.
Could you give an interpretation of the definition so is more intuitive? Seems quite disconnected from the idea of finitude. If this helps, this definition was given to me in the context of normed spaces.

Reading about sequential compactness might be a good place to start.  Here, instead of infinite sequences having (at least) one convergent subsequence, you require that all convergent subsequences of sequences that can be drawn from $A$ converge to a point in $K$.
